# How to execute spark-shell from file with nohup?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a scala script file that gets successfully executed via interactive spark-shell in a classic way: type spark-shell, paste script, wait till completion.

I want to be capable to leave this thing working and exit ssh session, get back to results when I need.

I tried this and it behaves strangely

```
spark-shell -i file.scala >> out.log 2>&1 &
```

It prints only several lines of usual spark output to out.log and then reports that the process has ended. When I do 'ps aux | grep spark' I see there is spark running among processes.

When I run this it behaves as expected, but I have to leave session open to have my results.

```
spark-shell -i file.scala
```

Is there a way to get spark-shell working with nohup properly?

I know there is spark-submit working with jars but it feels less intuitive, for a simple test I have to asseble a jar and do maven magic.

Comment: I would recommend writing a script to do the Maven stuff and then `spark-submit`.   Then at least it's just one thing to run.

Comment: I have similar situation and as soon as start the following command,   it is stopped with  "Stopped (tty output)"  message.    spark-shell -i file.scala >> out.log 2>&1 &

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same behavior of `spark-shell` with `nohup`. The reasons behind this are unclear, but one can use `tmux` instead of `nohup` as a work-around. A pretty good guide on how to use `tmux` can be found [here](http://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/).

Possible set of actions is as following:

```
$ tmux new -s session-name
$ ./bin/spark-shell
# do usual stuff manually
```

Then if you close the terminal window and exit ssh session, you can re-enter the `tmux` session like this:

```
$ tmux attach -t session-name
```

Answer (score 4):

I use a shell script to execute `spark-shell`, inside `my-script.sh`:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell < $HOME/test.scala > $HOME/test.log 2>&1 &
```

Read it somewhere by googling and tried it. It is working on my end.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to execute it on `aws-cli` then you use the below command ..

```
nohup bash -c "YOUR_COMMAND 2>&1 &"
```

So to execute the spark-shell

```
nohup bash -c "spark-shell -i  file.scala >> out.log 2>&1 &"
```

Comment: this works on normal cli as well, thanks @Arpan

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I recently discovered another solution:

`echo ":load myscript.scala" | nohup $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell [other args]`

where other args represent more arguments passed to the spark-shell (not to your script; I haven't tested that part). I have a df.write() call at the end of the script so the results are saved to HDFS - no need to have them printed on screen. Note I don't need an & at the end of the command.

I have tried closing the SSH connection and the spark-shell job keeps running tasks, according to the Spark UI :-)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but did you actually try to use the [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) command?

Simply using `&` to background a process does not prevent it from exiting if it receives a SIGHUP signal, which is what the process will receive when you log out.

Try this:

```
nohup spark-shell -i file.scala >> out.log &
```